# reading text from file into a variable of type float

Tags: python, casting

I have few members of my class that are initialized with `float("nan")`. At every call of a class member `next()` some data is read from a file and assigned to that member.

Since I am reading from a flat file, that makes every read retrieve a string: does it mean that my class member type changes from `float` to a string?

The file open by self.any_file  contains 1 number per line e.g.

```
      93.56
      20,25
       ...
```

Below the code

```
MyClass:
   __init__(self):
      self.any_member = float('nan')
      self.any_file   = open('myFile.txt', 'r')

   next(self):
      self.any_member = self.any_file.readline() 

      # is 'self.any_member' a string or still a float?
      #
      # better this way?
      # self.any_member = float(self.any_file.readline())
```

Would it be better to convert that line explicitly to float or Python does that already?

Comment: *"is 'self.any_member' a string or still a float?"* - why don't you `print type(self.any_member)` and find out? Also, note that in general **Python never implicitly coerces types** - it is dynamically *but strongly* typed.

Comment: Python can't read your mind. `self.any_member` will be a string because that's want [`self.any_file.readline()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=readline#file.readline) returns.

Comment: Good stuff! Thanks a lot for the prompt response. If you put it as real response I'll sign it as correct.